Apache Beam: Fixing 'PBegin object has no attribute windowing' Error in Dataflow Pipeline
I'm working on an Apache Beam Dataflow job to store enriched streaming data in Firestore. If any event data is missed during processing, I push those records to a BigQuery table. Below, I’ve shared the relevant code snippet.
The EnrichEventsWithFirestore class fetches necessary data for Firestore storage. I’m using tagged output to capture failed records and push them to BigQuery as shown in the pipeline. However, I keep encountering the error:
AttributeError: 'PBegin' object has no attribute 'windowing'
How do I fix it?
class EnrichEventsWithFirestore(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database
        self.client = None

    def setup(self):
        if not self.client:
            self.client = firestore.Client(project='temp_myself', database=self.database)

    def process(self, element):
        list_ids = []
        for ele in element:
            Id = ele[0]['Id']
            list_ids.append(self.client.document('cust_add', str(Id)))
        docs = self.client.get_all(references=list_ids)
        Id_map = {}
        for doc in docs:
            doc_dict = doc.to_dict()
            if doc_dict:
                Id_map[doc_dict['Id']] = {
                    "c_num": doc_dict.get('c_num', "NA"),
                    "ct_num": doc_dict.get("ct_num", "NA")
                }
        enriched_data = []
        for ele in element:
            tran_data, item_data = ele
            Id = int(tran_data['Id'])
            filename = str(tran_data['filename'])
            tdatetime = tran_data['tdatetime']
           
            if Id in Id_map:
                ct_num = Id_map[Id]['ct_num']
                c_num = Id_map[Id]['c_num']
            else:
                yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('discarded',
                    [{'Id': Id, 'filename': filename, 'tdatetime': tdatetime}]
                )
                continue

            tran_data["ct_num"] = ct_num
            tran_data["c_num"] = c_num
            enriched_data.append((tran_data, item_data))

        yield enriched_data

# Pipeline Code
def run(pipeline_args):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, save_main_session=True)
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    if pipeline:
        results = (
            pipeline
            | "Process File Firestore" >> beam.FlatMap(parseForFirestore, campaign__data)
            | "Window and Batch Data Firestore" >> beam.WindowInto(
                beam.window.FixedWindows(5),
                trigger=Repeatedly(AfterAny(AfterCount(100), AfterProcessingTime(5))),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
                allowed_lateness=600
            )
            | "Group Data Firestore" >> beam.GroupBy(lambda s: assign_random_int())
            | "Extract Values Firestore" >> beam.Values()
            | "Enrich Events with Firestore Data" >> beam.ParDo(
                EnrichEventsWithFirestore('temp_myself')
            ).with_outputs('discarded', main='not_discarded')
        )

        results.not_discarded | "Push Data to Firestore" >> beam.ParDo(InsertToFireStoreInBatches('temp_myself'))
        results.discarded | "Write to BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            'bq_table',
            create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
            ignore_unknown_columns=True,
            method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
            schema=tab_schema
        )
    
    pipeline.run()




Hey, slightly off topic. I am struggling to get beam and flink work on k8s. If you've run this on k8s can you please share your setup?

It looks like your pipeline does not have defined a starting point.
First transform in each apache beam pipeline is quite unique and expects to get PBegin object, instead of PCollection - like just a regular transformation.
PBegin is a special kind of object representing the beginning of the pipeline. You do not have a source defined - like beam.Create, beam.ReadFrom* etc.
So FlatMap gets PBegin, but expects to get PCollection - so the error.
Try to add some source between pipeline and beam.FlatMap transformation.

Hello @Pav3k. Can you help ke out with this question if you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79239130/python-sdk-beam-on-flink-on-k8s-error-failed-to-retrieve-chunk-for-tmp-staged

Sometimes you can jumpstart your pipeline with something like beam.Create([None]), but I've found that has consequences if the data produced downstream in unbounded.
