Python SDK Beam on flink on K8s error: failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/submission_environment_dependencies.txt
I am trying to setup beam on flink on k8s using the spotify flink on k8s operator. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the document.
https://github.com/spotify/flink-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md
I was able to deploy the flink operator on k8s. then the job manager, task manager, beam flink cluster and the beam job server.
But when I submit python yaml job from here: https://github.com/spotify/flink-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/beam_guide.md
The beam job is submitted to the cluster, I can see it if I postforward the job manager container. But the issue is, it gets stuck for ever.
when I looked into the logs, this was the error:
failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/submission_environment_dependencies.txt
I googled this error, there is something that they added to the SDK for GCP platform. But I am using PortableRunner of Flink.
beam_clink_cluster:

apiVersion: flinkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: FlinkCluster
metadata:
  name: beam-flink-cluster
spec:
  flinkVersion: 1.8.1
  image:
    name: flink:1.8.1
  taskManager:
    replicas: 2
    sidecars:
      - name: beam-worker-pool
        image: apachebeam/python3.7_sdk:2.18.0
        args: ["--worker_pool"]
  flinkProperties:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "1"

beam_job_server:
    apiVersion: batch/v1
    kind: Job
    metadata:
      name: beam-wordcount-py
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: beam-wordcount-py
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: beam-wordcount-py
              image: apachebeam/python3.7_sdk:2.18.0
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              command: ["python3"]
              args:
                - "-m"
                - "apache_beam.examples.wordcount"
                - "--runner=PortableRunner"
                - "--job_endpoint=beam-job-server:8099"
                - "--artifact_endpoint=beam-job-server:8098"
                - "--environment_type=EXTERNAL"
                - "--environment_config=localhost:50000"
                - "--input"
                - "/etc/ucf.conf"
                - "--output"
                - "/tmp/output"
          restartPolicy: Never

beam_python_job.yaml:
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: beam-wordcount-py
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: beam-wordcount-py
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: beam-wordcount-py
          image: apachebeam/python3.7_sdk:2.18.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: ["python3"]
          args:
            - "-m"
            - "apache_beam.examples.wordcount"
            - "--runner=PortableRunner"
            - "--job_endpoint=beam-job-server:8099"
            - "--artifact_endpoint=beam-job-server:8098"
            - "--environment_type=EXTERNAL"
            - "--environment_config=localhost:50000"
            - "--input"
            - "/etc/ucf.conf"
            - "--output"
            - "/tmp/output"
      restartPolicy: Never


Can you submit your app without job server? It should be Beam 2.18.0+. See https://github.com/spotify/flink-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/beam_guide.md#without-jobserver-beam-218-only

Hey! We finally figured it out. Instead of PortableRunner we used FlinkRunner with the uber argument. I am blanking out in the option name rn
